# How can I remove the space around the div tags

Tags: html, css, web

I have started to code a website as a side project. I am having a problem with the layout of it. I want all of the spaces between items to not be there but I have failed to find a method of doing this.
I have tried to remove the margin from some of the elements and this seems to have made no impact. This has left me at a dead end.

Image showing what I mean by gaps
[image: image description]

The blue lines show what spaces I would like to get rid off.

```css
   /*Header CSS*/
.container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0;
   margin-bottom: 0;
}

.header_img {
 width:100%;
 height:150px;
 margin:0;
}

.text {
 font-size:26px;
 position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color:red;
}

.strapline {
 font-size:22px;
 position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color:red;
}
/*Removes page margin*/
body {
    margin: 0;
}
/*Navigation Bar CSS*/
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #666666;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
/*Setting up page*/
.main_text {
 margin-left:15%;
 width:85%;
 position: fixed;
 height:100%;
 background-color: #b3b3b3;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
/*Text formating*/
.first_line_home_page {
 margin-left:15%;
 font-size:20px;
}

.heading {
 background-color:red;
}

.article_title {
  color:white;
  font-size:24px;
}

.article_intro {
 font-size:18px;
}

.article_strapline {
 font-size:18px;
 font-weight:bold;
}

.white_background {
 background-color:grey;
}
/*Images formating*/
.interesting_article_img {
 height:165px;
 width:330px;
 float: left;
}

img { 
 border: 0;  
}
```

```html
   <div class="container">
 <img src="https://www.freewebheaders.com/wordpress/wp-content/gallery/football/world-cup-goal-keeper-sport-website-header.jpg" class="header_img" alt="Error">
 <div class="text"> 
  <h1>The Football Informer</h1>
  <p class="strapline">The Home of Football</p>
 </div>
</div>

<ul>
 <li><a class="active" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
</ul> 

<div class="main_text">
 <p class="first_line_home_page">Welcome to The Football Informer. This is the place to keep up to date with the footballing world.</p>
 <div class="heading">
 <h1>Interesting Articles</h1>
 </div>
 
 <div class="white_background">
 <a href="http://thefootballfaithful.com/allardyce-reveals-cenk-tosun-struggles/" target="blank">
 <p class="article_title ">Allardyce reveals Cenk Tosun struggles.</p>
 <img src="https://i1.wp.com/thefootballfaithful.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/img_7476.jpg?resize=660%2C330" class="interesting_article_img" alt="Error">
 </a>
 </div>
 <p class="article_strapline">Less than a month after joining Everton for £27m, Sam Allardyce has revealed that Cenk Tosun is struggling to adapt to life in the Premier League.</p>
 <p class="article_intro">The Turkish international sat out of the Toffees’ 5-1 humbling at the hands of Arsenal on Saturday evening, with the once outcasted Oumar Niasse selected to start the game.<br>
 Speaking after the defeat, Allardyce that the 26-year-old has struggled with the ‘pace and physicality of the game.’</p>
 <br>
 <div class="white_background">
 <a href="http://www.skysports.com/football/news/11715/11237193/leeds-sack-head-coach-thomas-christiansen-after-cardiff-thrashing" target="blank">
 <p class="article_title ">Leeds sack head coach Thomas Christiansen after Cardiff thrashing</p>
 <img src="http://e0.365dm.com/17/09/16-9/20/skysports-thomas-christiansen-leeds_4110664.jpg?20170925180918" class="interesting_article_img" alt="Error">
 </a>
 </div>
 <p class="article_strapline">Leeds have sacked head coach Thomas Christiansen after a 4-1 thrashing at home to Cardiff on Saturday - their sixth Championship game without a win.</p>
 <p class="article_intro">Christiansen's side had been without a win since Boxing Day and a spate of ill-discipline had seen three different players sent-off in four games.<br>
 Leeds had been pushing for a place in the top six but slipped to 10th after the Cardiff defeat and the club announced his departure just over 24 hours later.<br>
 "Leeds United can confirm that head coach Thomas Christiansen has left the club," a statement read.
 </p>

</div>
```

Comment: assuming your style.css is in this code above and your js file isnt doing anything important?  please post all your code

Comment: My js file is not doing anything and is currently empty. This is currently all of my code.

Comment: looks like crap when i copy to local html, why dont you setup jsfiddle

Comment: also we do not have your images

Comment: if thats the "items" your even talking about.  please when using stackoverflow, be precise in asking your question. Nobody wants to do all of your work for you

Comment: Spaces around which elements? https://jsfiddle.net/jafarian/abxv4vuh/

Comment: Also you're opening a `<div>`, opening an `<a>`, then closing off the `<div>` before the `<a>`, why?

Comment: See the snippet I made for you. Please go to https://placeholder.com and find some images

Comment: - also go to https://validator.w3.org/ and validate your illegal HTML - you have at least 8 errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Headings Tag (h1 to h6) and paragraph tags have default margins. You can try to add,

```
   p, h1 {
     margin: 0;
   }
```

to your styles to remove the unwanted gaps cause by these tags. As for the header image, the container div is slightly bigger in height compared to the image tag. Add a ***height of 150px*** also to the ***container div*** to remove the unwanted gap or better if you set the ***height of the image tag to 100%*** and then the ***container div will have the static height of 150px***, this will make sure that the ***height of image tag will always follow the height of the container div***. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you mean by "spaces"? Is it between lines?

Assuming this is just margin between lines, you can set margin to 0. I took your code and made a codepen here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GQjdjR

The first line of the CSS I added `* {margin: 0;}` which removes the margin for all elements. I can't say this is a *good* idea, but without a sense of what you want it's hard to say.

You can also look into a CSS reset to remove the browser-imposed CSS rules, such as this:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```